# Captcha Code not working using php

Tags: php, image, captcha, imagettftext

My captcha code is not working, I am able to bring up the lines at back but the numbers are not visible in the captcha. The code is working perfect on localhost but not on my hosting website.

here's the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$text= $_SESSION['secure'];

$font_size =30;
$image_width= 110;
$image_height=40;

$image=imagecreate($image_width,$image_height);
imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);


for($x=1; $x<=30; $x++){
$x1 = rand(1,100);
$x2 = rand(1,100);
$y1 = rand(1,100);
$y2 = rand(1,100);
imageline($image, $x1, $x2, $y1, $y2, $text_color);
}

imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $text_color, 'font.TTF', $text);
imagejpeg($image);  
?>
```

Comment: you should definitely use recaptcha. its api is so easy to use, it'd be a crime not to.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) 
Can you help me with the code above? If you can figure out what the problem is?

Comment: comment this line: //header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); and see what error u get ?

Comment: @siamak.a.m I'm getting something like this >> CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality >> and a lot of rubbish things written: Check here www.pingcampus.com/mysql/generate.php

Answer (score 1):

I commented that line and i got this warning and notice:

```
Notice: Undefined index: secure in F:\xampp\htdocs\captcha.php on line 4 
Warning: imagettftext() [function.imagettftext]: Invalid font filename in F:\xampp\htdocs\captcha.php on line 23
```

so first check out the font location.
then check out that the $_SESSION['secure'] value and if it's empty check why that session is empty. hope it helps you.

Edited:
1. I saved the code in a php file in my localhost. 
2. commneted line that includes header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); cause it set the page mime-type as jpg 
3. i read the notice and the warning.
Anyway i think your problem is empty session value or check gd is enable in your server.

Comment: can you please give me a walkthrough about how were you able to get the errors exactly? Also i would like you to remind you that my code works perfectly on localhost, but not on my webhost

Comment: Check out the edit and put this code above the script: ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); to turn on the error_reporting.

Answer (score 0):

i guess youre missing the font on your webhosting server. try a free one, which is likeley installed on the server or just upload the font to your webhost an set the correct path to the fontfile

Comment: I have already uploaded the font on the host, i am now trying to define a particular path by using $_Server['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

Comment: I made a new variable which stores the location of the font file:
    
**$font= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysql/font.TTF';**

and used the function as

**imagettftext($image,$font_size,0,15,30,$text_color,$font,$text);
**

Still didn't work